# difference among static_cast<>, (int), and __float2int_rn() in cuda

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a question about the difference between type conversions in CUDA:

```
static_cast<int>(1.3f)
(int)1.3f
__float2int_rn(1.3f)
```

For `__float2int()` method, it is explained in CUDA documentations.
For the others, `static_cast` and `(int)` C/C++ style data conversion methods, what are their behaviours in CUDA?
Is it safe to use C/C++ style type conversion code in CUDA device code?
In my code, their behaviours are different from `__float2int()` provided by CUDA.

Comment: Without knowing anything about the `__float2int_rn` variant, I suspect it does *rounding* of the value (based on the `rn` suffix). The other two methods *truncate* the value (i.e. just cut of the decimal part). Also, in C++ you really shouldn't do C-style casting, it should generally be seen as a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: CUDA [claims adherence to a particular ISO C++ standard](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-cplusplus-language-support), with stated exceptions.  That would be my starting point for any question of the form "what is the behavior of this C++ construct in CUDA"?  Other than that I upvoted the answer, TIL.

Answer (score 3):

`__float2int_rn` has different behavior from the C style and C++ style casts.  The C and C++ style cats will truncate, which means it just removes the floating point part of the number and gives you just the whole part.  `__float2int_rn` will

> Convert a float to a signed integer in round-to-nearest-even mode.

and if we look up what *round-to-nearest-even* is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) we have

> A tie-breaking rule without positive/negative bias and without bias toward/away from zero is round half to even. By this convention, if the fractional part of x is 0.5, then y is the even integer nearest to x. Thus, for example, +23.5 becomes +24, as does +24.5; while −23.5 becomes −24, as does −24.5. This function minimizes the expected error when summing over rounded figures, even when the inputs are mostly positive or mostly negative.

> This variant of the round-to-nearest method is also called convergent rounding, statistician's rounding, Dutch rounding, Gaussian rounding, odd–even rounding,[6] or bankers' rounding.

> This is the default rounding mode used in IEEE 754 operations for results in binary floating-point formats (see also nearest integer function), and the more sophisticated mode[clarification needed] used when rounding to significant figures.

> By eliminating bias, repeated rounded addition or subtraction of independent numbers will give a result with an error that tends to grow in proportion to the square root of the number of operations rather than linearly. See random walk for more.

> However, this rule distorts the distribution by increasing the probability of evens relative to odds. Typically this is less important than the biases that are eliminated by this method[citation needed].

So while

```
static_cast<int>(1.3f)
(int)1.3f
__float2int_rn(1.3f)
```

all produce the same results, with

```
static_cast<int>(23.5f)
(int)23.5f
__float2int_rn(23.5f)
```

the first two will evaluate to 23 while the `__float2int_rn` call will result in 24.